# Redirect and pass a value from server side in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

I redirect to a page from a grid view by sending the message id with it. this is done in client side

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn_ViewDashBoard" ImageUrl="Styles/Images/dash.jpg" Enabled="True"
                                    Width="" runat="server" PostBackUrl='<%# Eval("MsgID", "ResponseMetric.aspx?MsgID={0}") %>'
                                    Text='Send' ToolTip="View DashBoard"></asp:ImageButton>
```

How can I do this in server side. I have a button on the page, when the button is clicked it has to redirect to responsemetric.aspx page with the msgID. I want to pass the msgid with the URL from server side, how to do that. thanks

```
protected void ViewDash_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         int msgid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["uNewmsgID"].ToString());        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly postback but if you are passing your parameter in the query string, this should work.

```
Response.Redirect(string.Format("ResponseMetric.aspx?MsgID={0}", msgid));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740517/postback-error-page-not-displayed-when-redirected-after-postback       can you look at my other question as well. Thanks